# Filter django admin many to one editor

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I filter the contents of a dropdown field in django's admin pages when editing an object?
Example:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)

class QuestionAdmin(TeacherModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['body', 'category']}),
    ]
    #Filter by request.user == creator ?
```

Comment: Hey @Rokner, please write a comment if answers do not fulfill your expectations or accept most satisfying one.

Answer (score 5):

You can override `formfield_for_foreignkey` method in admin

```
class QuestionAdmin(TeacherModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "category":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Category.objects.filter(creater=request.user)
    return super(QuestionAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is **no official way** to do it.

You can however use [get_field_queryset](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L201) hook that is defined in `BaseModelAdmin` and inherited by `ModelAdmin`. The solution would look like this:

```
class QuestionAdmin(TeacherModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['body', 'category']}),
    ]

    def get_field_queryset(self, db, db_field, request):
        # Bahaviour for your field
        if db_field.name == 'category':
            return db_field.remote_field.model.filter(creator=request.user)
        # Default behaviour unchanged
        return super(OrderAdmin,self).get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
```

Before applying this solution please think twice if you really need it, not being part of official API means you might get into trouble when somebody changes this hook without adding deprecation warning in advance.